# Const qualifiers and ampersand

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants

I'm getting confused about the `const` qualifier. I found and read a lot of article and similar questions such as http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/pointers/const_pointers.html.

What is not clear to me is why `g++` complain about this class member:

```
const string& const name;
```

but it doesn't complain about

```
string& const name;
```

My idea is to declare a constant pointer to a constant string value. I'm using `&` instead of `*` to avoid `NULL` pointers.

What am I missing?

The compiler error is the following:

```
‘const’ qualifiers cannot be applied to ‘const string& {aka const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&}’
  const string& const name;
                      ^
```

Comment: "My idea is to declare a constant pointer..." - `&` does not declare a pointer at all.

Comment: Perhaps the compiler is saying "you have told me once, why the ...."

Comment: You are confusing references and pointers. Look them up in the index of your favorite C++ reference book.

Comment: @CodyGray he didn't realise he had a C++ reference book - thought it was a pointer book

Comment: Downvoted because the premise of the entire question is broken. _"it doesn't complain about `string& const name;`"_ It most certainly does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`string& const name;` should fail too. References and pointers are different things.

Reference couldn't be const itself, it doesn't make sense. Unlike pointer, reference could not be bound again after initialized.

Failed demo with [gcc](http://rextester.com/TTYV34342) and [clang](http://rextester.com/BYM18149).

And see [What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57483/3309790)

Comment: You forgot to tell him what he is missing, like the difference between pointers and references.